# Firebase real_time database query doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm using Firebase real-time database in my Android project. My database scheme as below :

[image: database scheme]

I want to get best 10 scores. My query :

```
   val query = reference.child("users").orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10)
    query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                        val score: String = it.child(Constants.scoreKey).value as String    
                        Log.i(TAG,"score:"+score)               
                    }
            }
        })
```

I hope to see best 10 scores on logcat. But it didn't. I see random scores.
What is my mistake ?

Comment: Field `score` is a string so the sorting is done lexicographically, not numerically.  Does that explain what appears to be the "random" order?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, change the type of your `score` field from `String` to `int` or `long`, otherwise the order is done `lexicographically`.

There is no operator in Firebase and as far as i know nor in other databases that allow you to change this behavior. Instead, you will need to modify the data to get the behavior you want. If you want to go with the String value, store the values that are in the order you need them when sorted lexicographically. For numbers you can accomplish that by padding them with zeroes:

As an example:

- "0131" //zero added before
- "0132" //zero added before
- ......
- "1308"
- "1309"
- "1310"
- "1311"